# how to create a SMTP server

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I have an application that run on server,
I want that my application could received mail in order to start some function.
I would like to know what should I need to do in order to have this capability? 
Do I need to build SMTP server? if so, how should I do it?

Comment: You just need to be able to monitor an email account for messages (and possibly clear it out). Why would you need a whole SMTP server?

Comment: SMTP is for sending mail.  But I would agree with Oded... monitor an email (using a POP client in C#) and just look for new emails.

Comment: WCF might be a better solution

Comment: @JaredPeless: An SMTP Server is for receiving emails. It's the easiest solution if he knows how to configure the DNS server.

Comment: @Oded rather that using email to trigger some functionality from one application to another why not just use WCF to make that call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try: http://www.lumisoft.ee/lsWWW/download/downloads/ .
There is SMTP server component what you can use to recieve emails.
Or alternatively there is SMTP server written in C#, you can write message filter for server.
In filter you can access incoming message and do what ever you want with it.
--- Yes also as others suggested will work ok too, you just run simple mail server and get emails by pop3 or imap. Pop3 and Imap components and example applications also included in same link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use IIS6 to receive email and drop it into a specified folder.  Your app can then pick up those emails and do whatever it needs to with them.

Comment: how do I do it with IIS? as I do have IIS on my server.

Answer (score 1):

I have previously had some success using the [Chilkat POP3 component](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/email-features.asp) to programmatically monitor a POP3 account for incoming mail.

Answer (score 1):

Active the SMTP service in IIS. It drops emails in the `C:\inetpub\smtproot\drop` folder IIRC.

Then you just need a Mime parser to read the EML files. I used the one in [Lumisoft](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/mime_project.aspx) when I did the same thing.

Comment: what will be the mail address (how do I config it)?

Comment: You need to create an MX record in your DNS server which points at your server. Else just use `something@yourservername.yourdomain.com` or `something@your.ip.address`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use any Mailserver to receive the mail and have your application check the poxtbox every 1 minute to receive the mails.
When any mail arrived (or special subject as you need), you could execute your code.

For IMAP you could look at [this Library](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/imap-dotnet.asp)